# 3 T Finfet Leakage reduction circuit techniques (VLSI)

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, sleep, leakage-current, finfet

What are the circuit techniques to reduce leakage in a 3T Finfet (front and back gate shorted) circuit? Vth in a 3T Finfet is almost always constant, so there is almost no stack effect and hence sleep transistor techniques won't work in this case.

Comment: Data sheet link? Context? Stack effect? Sleep transistor?

Comment: Stack effect in FinFETs - https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7829722

Comment: Sleep Transistor -  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4027493

Comment: The links require an account login and hence may not be accessible to everyone. Consider adding another reference accessible to all, or include a *short relevant extract* from the IEEE papers directly into the question using the [edit] button.

Comment: Higher Vt is needed yet voltage drop and power up delay is a concern